# Some of my comments were deleted. Why or how did that happen?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I made 2 simple, technical comments, to a follow up to an answer for one of my questions here last night

[How to load common javascript files in development and on web server not using relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684795/how-to-load-common-javascript-files-in-development-and-on-web-server-not-using-r)

When I look today, these 2 comments are gone? Were they removed by someone, and if so, why?

Comment: Depends on what the comments were. Might have been flagged by users, deleted by moderators, part of a larger cleanup...

Comment: Could have been flagged as a) obsolete, b) too chatty, c) unconstructive, d) offensive e) something else and then deleted by a moderator. Could have been an entire comment thread was deleted as too chatty... Comments are ephemeral anyway, so don't expect them to last under all circumstances.

Comment: They were useful comments, explaining the reason why the answer did not work for me. The person asked me why his answer did not work, and I replied saying why.  This is terrible that any one can delete anything anyone write. I did not even get a copy of my deleted replies so it is lost.

Comment: With some exceptions, @Servy. I believe six offensive flags will kill a comment, and there are a few "blacklist" terms that need only a single flag to delete.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Right, forgot about that.

Comment: In my opinion from reading the surviving comments you delved into a discussion with other user. That's not the purpose of comments. While it happens a lot and I do it as well sometimes, it's totally understandable why such "discussions" are removed, to keep the place clean.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: That's three comment flags at max, not six.

Answer (score 10):

I deleted those comments because they were flagged, and it seemed to me they were not heading in a constructive direction. It was not only *your* comments deleted, though.

This isn't really about 'censorship', though; It's all about keeping the signal:noise ratio high.

Here are the removed comments:

> Ok, I installed XAMPP and changed things accordingly. The only problem I see now is that I have to use a local web server to look at my web pages. I have to have apache running on the PC and then in the browser I have to do localhost/index.htm for things to load OK. If however I just double click on an index.htm file as I used to do before, then it will fail, since it is trying to load scripts from "/scripts" now, which only works when pages are served by webserver. This is really annoying. This means I can't just look at my web pages on the PC without having a webserver server running first. - Steve H
>
> I am afraid this solution does not work for me. I need a solution that I can use without having to run a local web server. Using a local web server is nice for testing. And I will keep it. But I want to also be able to access my pages and navigate them using a browser on the PC without having a web server running. Using "/scripts/...." solution only works when pages are served by web server. I tried moving the tree to "c:/" but it still did not work. Windows does not think "/" is same as "c:/". I need a solution that works on PC without having to have a web server installed as prerequisite. - Steve H
>
> @SteveH What's wrong with a web server? - Joseph the Dreamer
>
> The problem is simple. I want to be able to go to the beach and browse my pages locally on my old laptop, and I do not want to install apache just to look at my pages, many times, I make an index.htm for local use on the PC only, and so I do not need to install and start apache each time. The problem with this solution is additional prerequisites needed to view a simple web page on a pc before uploading it to the server. The use of a web server just to browse local pages on a PC is a problem. There should be a way to do this without all this complicated setup... - Steve H
>
> and many times I double click on an index.htm file anywhere in my tree directly from the file explorer to bring up a firefox to view it. I can't do this any more with this set, since I have to go though web server each time and navigate to the file, which means I have to do localhost/../../../index.htm instead of simply clicking on an html file directly. (also have to start apache each time if it is not running) - Steve H

Comment: `"This has nothing to do with 'censorship'"`, well, technically that *is* censorship.  We just don't consider that a bad thing.  Users *don't* have the right to post whatever they want without it being deleted.

Comment: @servy Good point, actually. Worded poorly!

Comment: Moderating from mobile? Good thing you don't have fat fingers! ;)

Comment: Gee, it seems like those comments would have been best served by being edited into the question by the OP.

Comment: @shawizdoward You should hear the cursing when I'm trying to type a longish message!

Comment: @tinsoldiersandnixonscomin My head a'splode!

Answer (score 9):

You should assume, when posting comments, that they can be deleted at any time for any reason.

They are designed to be supplementary, and not a primary means of conveying information.  If what you have to contribute is truly valuable then it should have been incorporated into a question or answer.

Moderators are the only people who can delete any comment alone (other than the comment author).  They can delete comments for a number of reasons including:

> [image]

If there are enough flags on a comment it can also be deleted without moderator intervention, and comments containing certain blacklisted terms will be deleted if there is even a single flag on the post.

Comment: This answer is the important part missing from mine, and is a much more useful, generalized answer!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Because no answer is complete without red freehand circles...

Comment: Well, yes. That's what I was referring to. Of course.

Answer (score 2):

From the [comment privilege documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)

> What are comments?
>
> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.
>   They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not
>   generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are
>   deleted they're gone for good.
>
> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any
>   part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is
>   a privilege.

Notice that comments are **temporary**.

It is possible that your comments were deleted sooner than they should have been.

For future reference, I suggest that anything you want to be permanent should be in a question or answer.